# running or cumulative measure

Tags: dax, powerquery

I would appreciate any advises for my problem :
I have a list of stock with daily values (so several stocks and one value per day for each).
I'm trying to do a cumulative margin % on the total portfolio from the beginning of the year as a measure so i have the results on a daily basis.

So by example if the total portfolio value is 100 one day and 102 the day after and 104 the following day, i would like to have a measure with (for these 3 days) 0, 2, 4%.

I have a measure calculating the margin % of the whole portfolio per day (i can't have a column as the data is not portfolio but stock based) :

[image]

And what i would like to achieve is the following :

[image]

I tried to do a `=CALCULATE(sum(dailies[marge_daily_percent_measure]); FILTER(all(dailies);INT(dailies[Date (Year)])=[annee]))`
(the filter is to get the current year data) but the sum cannot be applied to the measure (he's looking for a column).

I also tried a TOTALYTD but i then have 2 issues : The Sum still cannot be applied to the measure and i also need the result on a daily basis.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: I would have created both columns in Power Query.  But I wonder about your logic.  If a portfolio goes up 1.37% on day 1, and then drops 3.03%, what does the 1.66% represent?  Since you are dealing with percent changes, and the base changes each day, does simple addition/subtraction return useful data?  Percent change for a period is usually calculated by comparing "today" with the start of the period; not by summing the daily changes.

Comment: yes, i will create these 2 columns in power query, my issue though is that i need these 2 columns on a daily basis whereas the main table i use have several stocks per day (i will probably deal with that).
on your point re the logic, you're fully right, however my goal is to compare with an index how am i performing so i guess my method is ok .
thanks Ron !

Comment: But you are using DAX. I'd suggest grouping main table by date; add column with your calcs in m code and, if you're going to compare with an Index, calculate your return the same as the Index, not by summing daily percentage change. You can do all that in M. Then use PiwerBI to create some attractive presentations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your table with stock prices looks like this

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 30 December 2021 | 104 |
| 31 December 2021 | 106 |
| 03 January 2022 | 107 |
| 04 January 2022 | 107 |
| 05 January 2022 | 106 |
| 06 January 2022 | 95 |
| 07 January 2022 | 106 |
| 10 January 2022 | 110 |

I have calculated a Margin measure, DAX below. And cumulative measure using `SUMX`.

### DAX: Margin

```
Margin =
VAR _SelectedDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Date] )
VAR _SelectedValue =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Value] )
VAR _PreviousDate =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ), 'Table'[Date] < _SelectedDate )
VAR _PreviousValue =
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ), 'Table'[Date] = _PreviousDate )
VAR Margin =
    DIVIDE ( _SelectedValue - _PreviousValue, _PreviousValue )
RETURN
    Margin
```

### DAX: Margin Cumulative

```
Cumulative Margin =
VAR _SelectedDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Date] )
VAR Cumulative =
    CALCULATE (
        SUMX ( VALUES ( 'Table'[Date] ), [Margin] ),
        'Table'[Date] <= _SelectedDate
    )
RETURN
    Cumulative
```

Bear in mind that the final percentage value you get from `Cumulative Margin` is not the same as the difference from the first value against the last value. In this case, `(110-104)/104 = 5.77%`. With the Cumulative, I get `6.91%`

### Output

[image]

Comment: this is perfect, thanks !! the Sumx made it for me :)

Answer (score 1):

One way I've built cumulative measures in the past is to do the following logic to filter on date. Assuming you use this in some kind of time-sliced view (like your table, or a linechart), this should only grab the dates on/before 'todays' date for each row.

```
_Cumulative_ClosedTasks = 
CALCULATE (      
   [_ClosedTasks],      
   FILTER (      
      ALL ('Date'[Date]),      
      'Date'[Date] <= MAX ('Date'[Date])  
   )    
)
```

(`[_ClosedTasks]` is just a basic SUM metric)

Does this approach work for your data?

Comment: thanks Samuel, unfortunately not. It works on the dates that i want but my issue really is on the [_ClosedTasks] as the data i want to sum up (to do the cumulative) is a measure (the 'marge_daily_percent_measure') and if i do 'CALCULATE(SUM([marge_daily_percent_measure]) etc ...' the SUM doesnt work as it uses only a column and not a measure. I hope it's more clear but thanks anyway :)