# getting max and min of a measure just the day the day it happens

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery

I have a measure giving me a running margin per day.
the output is like this :

[image]

I would like to spot the min and max of that measure the day it happens so i can plot it in a graph as a point (and not as a line) like this :

[image]

i tried the following measure :

```
max_gap_perf_cac :=MAXX ( VALUES ( dailies[Date] ); [Cac_port_gap] )
```

whereas my table is dailies and Date is the date column

The result of the measure is correct but when i put it in a pivot table i have the following result which doesnt allow me to plot the result in a graph :

[image]

Any help is welcome !
Edit : the initial measure to create the running margin was adressed in that question : [running or cumulative measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70633803/running-or-cumulative-measure)
Thanks

Comment: Is it a powerbi or excel problem? Add some dummy details so that others can recreate your problem / case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i found a solution, may not be the best one though.
I'm creating a name range for the first pivot table (the one with 2 columns on top) :

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$P$5;0;0;COUNTA(Sheet2!$P:$P)-1;2)
```

(the top left cell of the table is cell P5)

This name range is then the source of a power query (Add to the data model and only create connection).

In the power pivot table created by power query ("newtable") i then added 2 columns, one for the min and one for the max with the following formula (for the max, it's the same logic for the min) :

```
=IF(newtable[Cac_port_gap]=[max_gap_perf_cac];newtable[Cac_port_gap];blank())
```

Doesnt sound great but made the trick for me.